# Combinatorics and Probability

Tags: combinatorics

A class consists of 3 boys and 6 girls willing to form 3 groups of 3 called Groups A, B, C.

How many ways are there to assign them to the groups such that exactly 1 group has no boys?

Comment: My idea: $\frac{6!}{1!3!2!}\cdot\frac{3!}{2!1!}\cdot 3! $  Not sure.

Comment: Think of it this way. Given that you're supposed to have a group with 3 girls, this 1 group can be chosen in $6C_3$ ways. Now with the rest of the people, you need to partition $6$ people into 2 groups of 3 which has a straight forward solution. Multiply the value you obtain with $6C_3$ and you arrive at your answer.

Comment: Can you illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I made a small mistake in the above comment, now I've posted my explained thoughts as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *label* of the no boy group can be chosen in $3$ ways. For each such way, the girls who will be in that group can be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.

Now consider the group lowest in the alphabet which will have at least one boy. That group can have (1) $1$ boy or (ii) $2$ boys.

To count (i), the boy can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways, and for each choice of boy the $2$ girls can be chosen in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}$.

The same argument shows that the count of (ii) is $\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}$.

That gives a total of $18$. Multiply by $3\binom{6}{3}$.

Because there are many ways to count, we do the arithmetic. The total number of ways is $(3)(20)(18)$, which is $1080$.

**Remark:** The number $1080$ agrees numerically with the number you gave in a comment. Since reasons of space precluded giving a justification, it is not clear whether the *reasoning* was correct.

Comment: Thank you. Now what is the total number of ways in which they can be grouped into 3 groups of 3 irrespective of gender?   I did this: $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$ or is it $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!} * 3!$  ?

Comment: There is a difference between **named** groups, as in the A, B, C question, and unnamed groups. For named groups one way of counting gives $\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}=\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$. Another ways gives same answer directly. Your second proposed answer is not right. If the groups are **unnamed**, divide by $3!$.

Comment: My question is, why aren't we choosing labels in this case like you did before? If I use the method you did and I choose labels for every arrangement, it results in $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!} * 3!$

Comment: The $\binom{9}{3}$ comes from choosing who will be in group A. The $\binom{6}{3}$ comes from choosing which of the rest will be in group B.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A is the group without boys. A choice of three girls must be made from a total of six. So the number of possible assignments for group A is $\binom{6}{3}$. Then the number of assignments for group B is $\binom{6}{3}$ (since three girls are in group A, there are six people remaining to choose from). And there is only one way to assign the remaining three to group C. So there are $\binom{6}{3}^2$ ways to assign them to groups, assuming that A has no boys.

Make the same assumption (that the group has no boys) for B and then C. This means that there are 3$\binom{6}{3}^2$ ways to assign them to the groups with the given condition.

Note: this may not be correct, but hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: Andrew: What you say should help, but you missed two details. First, it's required that exactly one group has no boys, not just at least one. Your method of counting includes the possibility that groups A and C or both groups A and B both have no boys. You also double-count assignments that have two no-boy groups, because you count the unique assignment of all girls to both A and C twice: once when you assume A has no boys, then again when you assume C has no boys. I think if you fix the first oversight, the second one may not remain.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the double counting too. @SteveKass , is my solution right?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are $6$ girls, out of which we need to necessarily form a group with $3$ girls. That can be done in $6\text{C}_3$ ways.
2. Now that we've finished the no-boys group, the remaining $2$ groups have $3$ members each out of which $3$ are guys and $3$ are girls. We need to have at least $1$ girl in both the remaining groups so that no group other than the one which we already chose has all $3$ girls. This can be done in the following manner: You need to select select a girl for the remaining $2$ groups for sure. That can be done in $3\times2$ ways.
3. Now we can select the rest of the 4 people can be put in the 2 groups in $4\text{C}_2$ ways. Hence the answer is:$$6\text{C}_3 \times3\times2\times4\text{C}_2=720$$